# jira redirection from old url to new url

Tags: tomcat, redirect, jira

I have applied SSL for jira and it is working fine but the older tickets are cant able to open

https://jira.xyz.com---------------> I changed to this it is working fine

[http://jira.xyz.com:9000----------->](http://jira.xyz.com:9000-----------%3E) This is old URL and when i try this url it is prompting to https://jira.xyz.com

But when I try http://jira.xyz.com:9000/browse/ID-9997 it is not working

need to know how to redirect properly or Do in need to use any tool?